# Alterar Label do buton ao clicar e pegar o valor digitado

Tags: ios, swift

Boa tarde, tenho um botao na minha aplicação que o valor será alterado conforme o botao for selecionado, deve abrir um campo para o usuario digitar e consequentemente ele pega o valor digitado e altera o label.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var fieldInput: UITextField! // Campo
@IBOutlet weak var charOne: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var charTwo: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var charThree: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var charFour: UIButton!

var selectedButton: UIButton!
var savedText: String!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Atribuir delegate ao campo
    fieldInput.isHidden = true
    fieldInput.delegate = self
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textFieldInput: UITextField) -> Bool
{
    if (textFieldInput == self.fieldInput) {
        // Guardar o texto do campo
        savedText = textFieldInput.text
    }
    // Finalizar a edição
    textFieldInput.resignFirstResponder()
    return false;
}

@IBAction func didEditingEnd(sender: AnyObject) {
    // Acção associada ao campo
    selectedButton.setTitle(savedText, for: .normal)
    fieldInput.isHidden = true
}




//UILongPressGestureRecognizer associado a cada botão
@IBAction func didLongPressButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    if  sender is UILongPressGestureRecognizer &&
        sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.began {
        if let button = sender.view! as? UIButton {
            // Inicia alteração
            fieldInput.isHidden = false
            // Acção associada a cada botão
            selectedButton = button
        }
    }
}
}
```

Ele está reclamando do view, não sei o que está errado

Answer (score 1):

Pelo o que vi aqui você não está usando a assinatura correta do método textFieldShouldReturn que é:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool
```

Você também pode usar o método textFieldDidEndEditing do UITextFieldDelegate para pegar o valor do textField e setar como title do botão.

Fiz algumas alterações no seu código e funcionou corretamente aqui.
Abaixo está meu código, caso tenha alguma dúvida me pergunte que respondo quando tiver um pouco mais de tempo.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var fieldInput: UITextField! // Campo
@IBOutlet weak var charOne: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var charTwo: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var charThree: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var charFour: UIButton!

var selectedButton: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Atribuir delegate ao campo
    fieldInput.isHidden = true
    fieldInput.delegate = self
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool
{
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return false;
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    selectedButton.setTitle(textField.text, for: .normal)
    fieldInput.isHidden = true
    fieldInput.text = ""
}

//UILongPressGestureRecognizer associado a cada botão
func didLongPressButton(sender: Any) {
    guard let sender = (sender as? UILongPressGestureRecognizer) else {
        return
    }

    if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.began {
        if let button = sender.view! as? UIButton {
            // Inicia alteração
            fieldInput.isHidden = false
            // Acção associada a cada botão
            selectedButton = button
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Fábio, obrigado pelo código, porém ele não funcionou direito, quando eu clico no botão ele não está tendo ação nenhuma, porém eu queria saber o seguinte, estou um pouco confuso, pois realizei esse projeto em Android e agora preciso migrar ele para Swift, porém o que acontece, no Android, tenho o botão, quando o usuário aberta ele, abre um modal, podemos dizer assim, ai tem um campo para inserir valor, após ele inserir e confirmar a tela fecha e o texto dentro do botão é atualizado com o valor digitado, porém não estou conseguindo reproduzir isso, nem precisa ser 4 botoes, um já me atende

Comment: @AndreCabral o resto das configurações foram feitas no Interface Builder como imaginei que você teria feito. Se você adicionar isso no viewDidLoad() meu código deve funcionar para o primeiro botão:

`let longPressGestureRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didLongPressButton(sender:)))
        charOne.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGestureRecognizer)`