# Alterar Label do botao com valor digitado

Tags: ios, swift, swift-3

Tenho um aplicativo que quando tocar no botão deve abrir o teclado e o valor que o usuário digitar precisar ser inserido no label do botão, não sei como faço isso, alguém pode ajudar, no caso seria em swift 3

Comment: Duplicado de [Alterar Label do buton ao clicar e pegar o valor digitado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/224628/alterar-label-do-buton-ao-clicar-e-pegar-o-valor-digitado/225850#225850). Respondido na pergunta original.

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBAction func userInput(sender: UITextField) {
MeuBotao.setTitle(sender.text,for: .normal)
}
```

Comment: Nesse caso aonde tem que ser declarado o MeuBotao?

Comment: Cara você é iniciante no desenvolvimento pra IOS ? Você pode usar a própria ferramente de design para criar o botão na sua aplicação e colocar o nome que quiser pra ele.   Ou se quiser via código seria assim: let MeuBotao = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 50)).   Seria bom dar  uma lida em alguns tutoriais, acho que vai lhe ajudar bastante e também vai evitar que o pessoal de um downvote em você aqui no stackoverflow.

Comment: Eu não sou iniciante, só fiquei confuso porque o userInput que você colocou seria o nome do botão se não tiver enganado. mesmo com a ferramenta de design ele vai pegar e inserir por exemplo: @IBAction func userInput, o userInput seria o nome do botão, pelo que aprendi, se estiver errado me desculpe, realmente não tenho muita experiencia no desenv de ios

Comment: Desculpe, so pude reponder agora. Pode ficar tranquilo, não tem problema. Existem 2 tipo o label text e o name (Esse é o nome do botão como fosse seu id "Meu botao"). Na parte do design vai nas propriedades do botão que vc ve todas as opções que eles tem. boa sorte.

Comment: A propriedade text não existe no UIButton. O jeito correto é: `meuBotao.setTitle(sender.text, for: .normal)`.

Comment: Tem razao, no swift mudou , diferente do objectivC puro. Obrigado.

Comment: Pessoal, muito obrigado pelo auxilio, não sei se conseguir me expressar direito, mas assim, no Android eu fiz um app, que tenho um botão, quando o usuário seleciona ele, ele abre uma outra 'tela' podemos dizer que um modal, ai habilita um espaço pra ele inserir um valor, quando ele confirma esse modal é fechado e atualiza o texto dentro do botão, séria semelhante? ou teria que usar o longPress?